Is there a way to share tags alongside RAM-shared resource across accounts?
TL;DR: When, from account A, I share an AWS resource (say a VPC subnet) with account B using AWS Resource Access Manager (RAM), account B can see the resource but it has no tag despite resource having tags when account A looks at it.

I have an issue when dealing with multi-account (same organization) resource sharing and tags.
I have a dedicated network AWS account that creates VPC, subnets, security groups, Internet and NAT gateways, … for other AWS accounts to spawn/configure their EC2 instances in.
Resource are shared using the AWS Resource Access Manager (RAM).
The network account placed tags on resources, like the various subnets.
Example:
$ AWS_PROFILE=account_A \
    aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-0c251fd621263e58f \
    | jq '.Subnets[].Tags'
[
  {
    "Key": "Acme:Client",
    "Value": "ACME"
  },
  {
    "Key": "Acme:Project",
    "Value": "TagRamBugDemo"
  }
]

$ AWS_PROFILE=account_B \
    aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-0c251fd621263e58f \
    | jq '.Subnets[].Tags'
null

According to AWS tag documentation it's "normal":

When you tag public or shared resources, the tags you assign are available only to your AWS account; no other AWS account will have access to those tags. For tag-based access control to shared resources, each AWS account must assign its own set of tags to control access to the resource.

Because I need to read tags from accounts B (e.g. tags tells what it can be done with the subnets): is there a workaround this limitation so that my account B can read the tags (a copy is fine)?
Note:

All accounts are in the same AWS organization.
I am using Terraform v1.9.4 and the hashicorp/aws v5.62 provider.

Ideas:

Dump tags from account A using Terraform and store them in some AWS resource (read-only S3?) and read them from account B via Terraform (like this SO answer).
Dump tags from account A using Terraform output, write them in a .tf file for the account B to read them and apply them when it runs it's terraform plan.
Dump tags from account A using AWS API (via awscli or other mean) and apply them to shared resources using account B credentials.


While sharing resources with RAM, tags on the resource won't be shared along with the shared resource.
If you're using the name from the name tag on the resources to somehow reference it, then you need to add the name tag key-value pair again to the shared resource in the accounts where the resource is shared or you can reference it using the ID or ARN.
